# SQL Query for Average big record

Tags: java, mysql, select, charts

I have a table  `user_test`

with columns `id ,name, race_number , speed`

A user can have over `100K` races as well.

I want to produce graph/report but I don't want to display graph for all the races but instead group them or take some average and then display.

Example:

A user has 1000 races then I would like to show graph liek

```
|
|
|
|
|
|
|    ~  
|  ~    ~ 
| ~        ~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~~ ~
|  
|
|- -10 - - - - 100- -- - 200- - - - 400- -- - - - - - 100- -
```

Above `chart` is displaying average speed during those races.

Is there anyway I can write a query for that?

I have not tried anything as I have no idea if someone at least point me in right direction or any reference would be enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    100*floor(race_number/100) race_number_group,
    avg(speed) average_speed
FROM user_test
GROUP BY floor(race_number/100);
```

This will give you average speed for the races in groups of 100. Feel free to change the grouping.